# Python count number of occurrences

Tags: python, count, row

How would I go about reading ws1 column F starting at row 4 and counting the number of times the value 0 occurs and then write that number to ws3 column M row 2? This would need to be part of my for loop, because it would have to do this for each file that I have.

```
import openpyxl as xl; 
import os
 
 
input_dir = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\NNM'
template = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\template.xlsx'
summary = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\summary.xlsx'
newFile = 'Comparison.xlsx'
 
 
 
 
files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_dir)
         if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith(".xlsx")]
 
 
wb3 = xl.load_workbook(template) 
ws3 = wb3.worksheets[0] 
 
i=0
ii=0
 
 
for file in files: 
   input_file =  os.path.join(input_dir, file)
   wb1=xl.load_workbook(input_file)
   ws1=wb1.worksheets[0]
 
    
   wb2 = xl.load_workbook(summary) 
   ws2 = wb2.worksheets[1]
 
     
   ws3[f'A{i+2}']=ws1['A1'].value[28:]
   ws3[f'D{i+2}']=ws1['B4'].value
   ws3[f'E{i+2}']=ws1['D4'].value
   ws3[f'I{i+2}']=ws1['B'][-1].value
   ws3[f'J{i+2}']=ws1['D'][-1].value
   ws3[f'O{i+2}']=ws1['E'][-1].value 
   ws3[f'N{i+2}']=ws2[f'I{ii+6}'].value   
   i += 1
   ii +=1          
    
    
 
   wb3.save(newFile)
```

Comment: Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: use `for`-loop to check rows.